# How to Learn Stability Theory

Tags: logic, reference-request, model-theory

I wish to learn stability theory, but I don't know what in stability theory (and possibly related areas) from which source.

I've been reading Pillay's *Introduction to Stability Theory* just because my friends were reading it, but I struggle to read that book.

I'd like a book that gives motivations and/or big pictures, i.e., a book with nontrivial amount of prose.
[Marcija and Tofollori's book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-94-007-0812-9) seems good in this regard,
but its exposition is focused on $\omega$-stability only (which might or might not be OK with me for now).  I don't know anybody recommending that book, either.

I'd like a book with few errors or at least with a public list of errors, since I feel greatly frustrated and unmotivated by errors.  Tent and Ziegler's book satisfies this criterion.  It makes an interesting choice of explaining simplicity first.  I am not sure if studying simplicity first is good for me.

What do people recommend to a student trying to study stability theory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no book on stability theory that I would really recommend to students (especially for self-study). Ziegler, for instance, is not famous for his didactic abilities .... Moreover, think a beginner would profit from concentrating on stability (or nip) and postpone the study of simplicity.

[Pierre Simon guide to nip theories](http://www.normalesup.org/~simon/NIP_guide.pdf) is modern and a well-written introduction to nip theories (which can also help to understand stability).

[Artem Chernicov's notes](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~chernikov/teaching/StabilityTheory285D/StabilityNotes.pdf) are mainly taken from Tent and Ziegler's book but here and there he adds some interesting insight.

The good old book of [Poizat](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4419-8622-1) has a maverick style, but really makes some effort to explain ideas.

**EDIT.** I forgot to say that, *before even think of adventuring into stability theory*, you should be very confident with basic model theory. I.e., compactness/saturation arguments, back-and-forth, imaginaries, etc.

Advanced texts are often lazy when it comes to introducing the basics (often they simply rewrite the 60yrs old book of Chang&Keisler). So you are better off with more introductory texts

Very basic texts:

[Good old fashioned model theory](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~hsimmons/BOOKS/ModelTheory.pdf)

[Fundamentals of Model Theory](http://www.math.toronto.edu/weiss/model_theory.pdf)

An intermediate text:

[A crèche course in model theory](https://github.com/domenicozambella/creche/raw/master/creche.pdf)